# how to iterate through nested array items separately

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a three-dimensional array, for example:

`var array = [[1,0][3,3][2,1][0,8]]`

and I want to do something with the first item in each sub-array, but something else with the second item in each sub-array.

So, for example, I would like to find the sum of `array[0][0], array[1][0], array[2][0]` and so on for `array.length`. But, I would like a separate result for `array[0][1], array[1][1], array[2][1]`, etc.

I'm still learning javascript (very slowly) and, if possible, I would like to be pointed in the right direction, rather than getting a ready-made solution. I've been looking for possible solutions, and I think I may need a nested `for` loop, but I'm not sure how to structure it to get all the values.

I've been trying something along the lines of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    return array[i][j];
  }
}
```

but I don't understand what's happening well enough to manipulate the result.

If anyone could steer me in the right direction toward finding a solution, that'd be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This line is wrong: `for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {` I hope my answer will help you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using `.reduce` - on each iteration, add the first array value to a property of the accumulator, and do whatever you need to with the second array value, assigning its result to another property of the accumulator. For example, let's say for the second items, you wanted to get their product:

```js
const input = [[1,0],[3,3],[2,1],[0,8]];
const { sum, product } = input
  .reduce(({ sum=0, product=1 }, [item0, item1]) => ({
    sum: sum + item0,
    product: product * item1
  }), {});
console.log(sum, product);
```

In the above code, the accumulator is an object with two properties, `sum` (starts at 0) and `product` (starts at 1). Inside the `reduce`, an object is returned, with the new `sum` being the old `sum` plus the first item in the array, and with the new `product` being the old `product` multiplied by the second item in the array. (of course, the resulting product is 0 because in the first sub-array, the second item is 0)

Also note that arrays always need commas separating each array item - you need to fix your input array's syntax.

Of course, you can also `for` loops if you have to, but I think array methods are preferable because they're more functional, have better abstraction, and don't require manual iteration. The same code with a `for` loop would look like this:

```js
const input = [[1,0],[3,3],[2,1],[0,8]];
let sum = 0;
let product = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  const [item0, item1] = input[i];
  sum += item0;
  product *= item1;
}
console.log(sum, product);
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I can understand the `for` loop at the bottom, but I will follow your advice about array methods and learn more about the `.reduce` method and try to get to grips with the syntax above. Thanks again for the explanation - it's really helpful for a beginner.

Comment: Also thanks for the variables with sum & product too (having two different calculations helped me get a better sense of what's going on)

Answer (score 1):

You just need one for-loop since you just have one array with arrays inside where you know the indexes you want to proccess. So it would be something as follows:

```
let sum1 = 0;
let sum2 = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum1 += array[i][0];
    sum2 += array[i][1];     
}
console.log('sum1: ', sum1);
console.log('sum2: ', sum2);
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! this makes so much more sense now. i was definitely overcomplicating it. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for help with pointing you in the right direction, I would suggest you start with simple `console.logs` to see what's happening (comments are inline):

```js
var array = [[1, 0],[3, 3],[2, 1],[0, 8]];

var results = [0, 0]; // this array is to store the results of our computation

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // for each subarray in array
  console.log('examining subarray ', array[i]); 
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) { // for each element in subarray
    if (j === 0) {
      console.log('...  do something with the first element of this array, which is: ' + array[i][j]);
      results[j] += array[i][j]
    } else if (j === 1) {
      console.log('...  do something with the second element of this array, which is: ' + array[i][j]);
      // do some other computation and store it in results
    }
  }
}

console.log('Final results are ', results);
```

Comment: this is really useful - thanks. i should make this more of a habit so i can see what's going on better rather than trying to store the values mentally(!) it really helped to have those strings in the console too, so thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake on the second line. You need to iterate through the nested array and then take the value from the main array.

```js
const mainArray = [[1, 0], [3, 3], [2, 1], [0, 8]];

for (let i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
  const nestedArray = mainArray[i]
  for (let j = 0; j < nestedArray.length; j++) {
    const value = mainArray[i][j]
    switch(j) {
      case 0:
        console.log(`first item of array number ${i+1} has value: ${value}`)
        break;
      case 1:
        console.log(`second item of array number ${i+1} has value: ${value}`)
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the array you have posted is a 2d array not a 3d array.

And the nested for loop you have posted is perfect for what you want.
Your first for statment is looping through the the frist deminsion of your array. the second is getting each index in the second array

```
var array = [[1,0],[3,3],[2,1],[0,8]]
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  //This loop over these [1,0],[3,3],[2,1],[0,8] 
  //So i on the first loop is this object [1,0] so so on
  for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    //This will loop over the i object
    //First loop j will be 1
    //Here is where you would do something with the index i,j. 
    //Right now you are just returning 1 on the first loop
    return array[i][j];
  }
}
```

I hope this help your understanding

Comment: thanks for the correction, and sorry for the mistake. the difference between the dimensions makes sense to me now.

Comment: No problem. If your questions is answered, please remember to mark your question as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for...of` loop along with destructuring like so:

```
for(let [a, b] of array) {
   // a will be the first item from the subarrays: array[0][0], array[1][0], ...
   // b will be the second: : array[0][1], array[1][1], ...
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
let array = [[1, 0], [3, 3], [2, 1], [0, 8]];

for(let [a, b] of array) {
   console.log("a: " + a);
   console.log("b: " + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using a debugger within your loop would be a good way to watch and understand each step of the loop
- Using the forEach method would be a clearer approach to loop through the array and its children

```js
const items = [[1, 0],[3, 3],[2, 1],[0, 8]]
let results = {}

items.forEach((item, index) => {
  // debugger;
  item.forEach((subItem, subIndex) => {
    // debugger;
    if (results[subIndex]) {
      results[subIndex] = results[subIndex] + subItem
    } else {
      results[subIndex] = subItem
    }
  })
})

console.log(results) // { 0: 6, 1: 12 }

// *********EXPLANATION BELOW ************
```

```js
const items = [[1, 0],[3, 3],[2, 1],[0, 8]]

// store results in its own key:value pair
const results = {}

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
// forEach is a more readable way to loop through an array
items.forEach((item, index) => {
  // use console.log(item, index) to see the values in each loop e.g first loop contains `item = [1,0]`
  // you can also use a debugger here which would be the easiest way to understand the iteration
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger
  // debugger;

  // loop over item (e.g [1,0]) to get subItems and their index
  item.forEach((subItem, subIndex) => {

    // get the result from previous sums from `result` 
    // and add them to the current subItem values
    // if there was no previous sum(i.e for first entry) 
    // use subItem as the first value.
    if (results[subIndex]) {
      results[subIndex] = results[subIndex] + subItem
    } else {
      results[subIndex] = subItem
    }

    // Below is a oneliner way to do line 16 to 20 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator
    // results[subIndex] = results[subIndex] ? results[subIndex] + subItem : subItem
  })
})

console.log(results) // { 0: 6, 1: 12 } the results of `array[0][0],array[1][0]...` are in 0 and the result of `array[0][1], array[1][1]...` are in 1 and so on.
```

Comment: thanks for the all the useful and clearly explained comments. also for the global points about using a debugger - i will try to make that a habit. i will also read up more on the `forEach` method now i can see how it might be used. thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Obligatory one-liner to bake your noodle.

```js
console.log([[1, 0], [3, 3], [2, 1], [0, 8]].reduce((p, c) => [p[0] += c[0], p[1] += c[1]]));
```

Comment: Instead of baking noodles how about instead explaining what the code does for the JS beginner?

Comment: For starters, there were no fewer than 4 answers when I submitted my example. I'm simply showing that it can be done a different way. @CertainPerformance already explained the reduce method in his answer.